# split String accept some characters

Tags: c#, string, split

I have some trouble with split string.

My String:

```
"SG_ PJB_ : 1|10@0+ (0.25,-60) [-60|195.75] "Degrees Celcius"  PCM,TCM,AFCM";
```

I would like to have:

```
SG_
PJB_ 
1
10
0+
0.25
-60
-60
195.75
Degrees Celcius
PCM
TCM
AFCM
```

my Code i have tried:

```
string s = "SG_ PJB_ : 1|10@0+ (0.25,-60) [-60|195.75] \"Degrees Celcius\"  PCM,TCM,AFCM";
string[] res = s.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', ':', '|', '@', '(', ')', '[', ']', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
{
   // Console.WriteLine("           ");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", res[i]);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

But it splited "Degrees Celcius" in 2 arrays. what should i do?

Comment: `Degrees Celcius` has a space there. Of course it got split. You can't achieve what you are asking for in a single `string.Split`.

Comment: should I make 2 splits? split firstordeufault till " and lastordefaut from "?

Comment: You can split on `"`, then split the stuff before the first `"` and then stuff after `"` on the other items. However, this assumes you will only ever have a single pair of `"` in the string.

Comment: Replace "Degrees Celcius" with "#!2321DC", split, replace "#!2321DC" with "Degrees Celcius" and you are good to go.

Comment: Maybe split (...,10,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); and then split the rest once more

Comment: t3hn00b: but if i have another string with same structur but with other parameters then i cant replace like u said

Comment: What's different - Degrees Fahrenheit, Degrees Kelvin? Just replace those too with something unique and then handle them with an if/switch when you're iterating the array

Comment: Or if it's just a Degree followed by some other string why not just make it like `if(res[i] == "Degree") { Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", res[i], res[i+1]); i++}`

Comment: lol but if i got "" or thousand other parameters so how can i do that?

Comment: it doesn't have to be degree, it could be anything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17920/discussion-between-t3hn00b-and-uni-le)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way:

```
var result = input.Split(new[] { '"' }).SelectMany((s, i) =>
  {
      if (i%2 == 1) return new[] {s};
      return s.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', ':', '|', '@', '(', ')', '[', ']', ';' },
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: 1 question more, how do i know the index of each array using it?

Comment: @UniLe: Don't understand, could you give example

Comment: because this is not string array anymore, its using linq, example i want to have control of splited "Degrees Celcius" and put it in a table cells. i did it with x=res[10] means x= "Degress Celcius";

Comment: @UniLe: Back to array, use `ToList` or `ToArray`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17923/discussion-between-uni-le-and-cuong-le)